# Does Scanner input work in the main method only?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

As you may have seen from my other questions, i am designing a noughts and crosses game. I started off by designing it and writing tests for it which i managed to make them all pass. So technically, i play the game with the tests.

Now i wanted the game to have some interaction with the user, so i inserted the main method in my game class. I already have methods to make a move and to determine if its a valid move or not. When i try and incorporate the Scanner inside the methods which already exist and use the next() or nextLine() method of scanner it doesn't work. However when i put the same code in the main method, it works and asks me for input on the console.

Does the Scanner only work on the main method? if so what alternatives do i have to get input through console for my game?

answers with examples would be appreciated due to my basic competency

Below is what I have

```
 public static void main (String args []){

}

public boolean playMove (player player, String value, int index) {
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Enter Value");
value = in.next();

}
```

Maybe my error is in leaving the main method blank. Because I already have methods that do the functions i wanted to and all the tests pass, i dont want to move stuff to the main method. Any suggestions please?

Thanks

Comment: Questions with example code and more specific than "doesn't work" would be appreciated due to our lack of ESP. And of course the answer is no, you can use that object anywhere ... just like any other object.

Comment: No, of course not. That would just be stupid. Code please. (Your problem lies elsewhere and the belief that it has to do with the *location* of where an *arbitrary* Scanner object is used is incorrect.)

Comment: Can you paste some code?

Comment: "examples would be appreciated ..." statements are not appreciated. Please show us ***your*** examples first so that your question is answerable. How the heck else can we see where your error is?

Comment: No code sample, so this is a guess: you declared Scanner as 'static'. Don't. Static fields can only be referenced in static methods (like the main method).

Comment: _Only the main method gets executed_. So, if you want your program to do something, you should put something in main. If you leave it blank, it does nothing. (Tests work a bit different, there is a 'hidden' main method that starts all your tests.)

Answer (score 2):

Works just fine.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(test());
    }

    private static String test() {
        Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
        return stdin.nextLine();
    }
}
```

My assumption is that you have a scope issue going on, post your code.

/e1
If you want anything to happen, you have to call it in the main method. Instead of leaving your main method blank, you need to (probably) have a [game loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming#Game_structure). In this case, if you only want to call that method, add `playMove(null, null, 0)` to work your `Scanner`.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. Please look at edited question - Maybe my error is in leaving the main method blank. Because I already have methods that do the functions i wanted to and all the tests pass, i dont want to move stuff to the main method. Any suggestions please?

Comment: That means i will have to change the playMove() modifier to static because it will be called in the main method which is static itself. Is that OK? any other way i can make this work without having the method static? anything else i can fling in the main method? Thanks in advance

Comment: @uncleB Yes, the method would have to be static.